# Как увеличить сумму в корзине определенного товара

Tags: корзина, javascript, интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте.

Надо увеличить сумму товара перенесённого в корзину на столько раз сколько его туда перенесли.
Вот код:

```
.bind('dragover', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
})
.bind('dragenter', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
})
.bind('drop', function (evt) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    var kolvon = $(".asde li").length;
    var id = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text'),
        post = $('#' + id),
        cartList = $("#cart ul"),
        total = $("#total span"),
        allzakaz = $("#allzakaz i"),
        price = $('p:eq(0)', post).text(),
        prevCartItem = null,
        notInCart = (function () {
            var lis = $('li', cartList),
                len = lis.length,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                var temp = $(lis[i]);
                if (temp.data('id') === id) {
                    prevCartItem = temp;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } ()),
        quantLeftEl, quantBoughtEl, quantLeft;

    if (notInCart) { 
        prevCartItem = $('<li />', {
            'id' : id,
            data : { id : id }
        }).prepend($('<span />', {
            'class' : 'cardoffer',
            text : $('a:eq(2)', post).text(),
        })).prepend($('<span />', {
            'class' : 'quantity',
            text : '0'
        })).prepend($('<span />', {
            'class' : 'price',
            text : price
        })).prepend($('<button />', {
            'class' : 'delete',
            'id' : id,
            text : '?'
        })).appendTo(cartList);
    }

    quantLeftEl = $('p:eq(3) span', post);
    quantLeft   = parseInt(quantLeftEl.text(), 10) - 1;
    quantBoughtEl = $('.quantity', prevCartItem);
    quantBoughtEl.text(parseInt(quantBoughtEl.text(), 10) + 1);
    quantLeftEl.text(quantLeft);

    if (quantLeft === 0) {
        post.fadeOut('fast');
    }

    total.text((parseFloat(total.text(), 10) + parseFloat(price.split('?')[0])).toFixed(0));

    var post2 = $('#total');
    totales = $('span:eq(0)', post2).text();
    $("#allzakaz").html(totales);
    $("#allzakaz1").html(totales);

    var kolvo = $(".asde li").length;
    if (kolvo == 0) {var textkolvo = 'Заказов';}
    if (kolvo == 1) {var textkolvo = 'Заказ';}
    if (kolvo >= 2 && kolvo <=4) {var textkolvo = 'Заказа';}
    if (kolvo >= 5 && kolvo <=20) {var textkolvo = 'Заказов';}
    if (kolvo == 21) {var textkolvo = 'Заказ';}
    if (kolvo >= 22 && kolvo <=24) {var textkolvo = 'Заказа';}
    if (kolvo >= 25) {var textkolvo = 'Заказов';}
    $("#kilvos").html(kolvo+" "+textkolvo);
    $("#kilvos1").html(kolvo+" "+textkolvo);

    $("#counte").html(kolvo);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/card/',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: {'idthem':id},
        success : function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    evt.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Вот HTML, надо заметь цену гдеclass=price

<li id="3"><button class="delete" id="3">?</button><span class="price">548</span><span class="quantity">2</span><span class="cardoffer">Dress Core Falie</span></li>

Comment: @Qiker, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: > Надо увеличить сумму товара перенесённого в корзину на столько раз сколько его туда перенесли. Вот код

Немного ощутил себя фрилансером (от слова бесплатный).

Comment: Вывел кол-во каждого товара в переменную:
это var asd = quantBoughtEl.text(); написал ниже этой строчки: quantLeftEl.text(quantLeft);

Вот сам код отвечающий за вывод суммы товара, но он прописан выше, выше указанных кодов:
.prepend($('<span />', {
'class' : 'price',
text : price
}))

Comment: > $('.quantity', prevCartItem)

этот объект это input?

> но он прописан выше

есть возможность перенести его ниже? или можно найти тот тег, и туда положить новое значение.